# Consulta linq en multiples columnas no esta dando resultado c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-8.0

Tengo la siguiente consulta en C#

```
 public ActionResult ListSearch(string txtbuscar, int? SelectCampo,  DateTime? From, DateTime? To)
    {
        DataTable dtDetalle = new DataTable();

        var user = db.MtoUsuarios.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        if (user == null)
        {
            RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }


        if (From > To)
        {
            TempData["SelectOption"] = 1;
        }

        var query = db.MtoInvesMercado.ToList();

                                             

        if (txtbuscar != string.Empty)
        {

            query = query.Where(p => ((p.OficioCAASolIm != null) || p.OficioCAASolIm.Contains(txtbuscar.Trim())) ||
                                     ((p.OficioDBTSolIm != null) || p.OficioDBTSolIm.Contains(txtbuscar.Trim())) ||
                                     ((p.OficioImEnvia != null) || p.OficioImEnvia.Contains(txtbuscar.Trim())) ||
                                     ((p.Descripcion != null) || p.Descripcion.Contains(txtbuscar.Trim())) ||
                                     ((p.NumeroInvestigacion != null) || p.NumeroInvestigacion.Contains(txtbuscar.Trim())) ||
                                     ((p.Comentarios != null) || p.Comentarios.Contains(txtbuscar.Trim())) ||
                                     ((p.ComentariosCCA != null) || p.ComentariosCCA.Contains(txtbuscar.Trim())) ||
                                     ((p.ComentariosDBT != null) || p.ComentariosCCA.Contains(txtbuscar.Trim())) ||
                                     ((p.OficioDBTSolicitaPMR != null) || p.OficioDBTSolicitaPMR.Contains(txtbuscar.Trim())) ||
                                     ((p.ComentariosPMR != null) || p.ComentariosPMR.Contains(txtbuscar.Trim()))
                              ).ToList();

   
        }




        switch (SelectCampo)
        {
            case 1:// fecha de registro
                query = query.Where(c => c.FechaRegistro >= From && c.FechaRegistro <= To).ToList();
                //(a.Start.Date >= startDate.Date && a.Start.Date <= endDate)
                break;
            case 2:// Fecha Oficicio CCA
                query = query.Where(c => c.FechaCCA >= From && c.FechaCCA <= To).ToList();
                break;
            case 3:// Fecha DBT Solicita IM
                //query = query.Where(c => c.fecha >= From && c.FechaDBTSolPMR <= To).ToList();
                break;
            case 4:// Fecha Entrega IM
                query = query.Where(c => c.FechaIM >= From && c.FechaIM <= To).ToList();
                break;
            case 5:// Fecha DBT envía IM a CCA
                query = query.Where(c => c.FechaDBTEnvia >= From && c.FechaDBTEnvia <= To).ToList();
                break;
            case 6:// Fecha DBT Solicita PMR
                query = query.Where(c => c.FechaDBTSolPMR >= From && c.FechaDBTSolPMR <= To).ToList();
                break;
        }


        dtDetalle = Utilities.LINQResultToDataTable(query);

        Session["SessionMtoInvesMercados"] = dtDetalle;

        return View("_ListResult",query);
    }
```

el problema radica en aquellos campos que en mi tabla no tienen información como es el caso de comentarios, al legar a ese campo me muestra el siguiente error.

```
WebDBT.Models.MtoInvesMercado.OficioCAASolIm.get devolvió null.
```

hay alguna forma de evitar ese problema cuando los campos donde voy a buscar no tengan información.

por su ayuda gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ya estas verificando si los valores son null,

```
query = query.Where(p => ((p.OficioCAASolIm != null) || **NULL**.Contains(txtbuscar.Trim()))
```

el problema es que tenes un || y deberias tener &&, caso contrario si es null intentara evaluar la segunda parte de la condicion y al ser NULL la function contains va a tirar exception.